# Ansible How to create XML file or exec shell script if task is failed or host unreachable

Tags: ansible

I've written a playbook which backup network devices configuration. My playbook is worked.

```
- name: run backup configuration
  hosts: HOST_NAME
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  vars:
    date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d') }}"
    backup_dir: "/backup/backup-{{ date }}"
    cli:
      host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
      username: <username>
      password: <password>
  tasks:
    - sros_command:
        commands: <command backup>
        provider: "{{ cli }}"
      register: config

    - copy:
        content: "{{ config.stdout[0] }}"
        dest: "{{ backup_dir }}/backup_conf-{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt"
```

But in case of host unreachable or not be able to run backup command or task failed. If this situation is happens, Can we write playbook to create XML or exec shell script? Because I've to send alarm to monitoring tools.

Please kindly help to advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ignore_errors` and `ignore_unreachable` keywords at either a play, block, or task level. This will allow the play to continue and you can use the registered result as a conditional for future tasks.

For example (at a play level):

```
- name: run backup configuration
  hosts: HOST_NAME
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local

  ignore_errors: yes
  ignore_unreachable: yes

  vars:
    date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d') }}"
    backup_dir: "/backup/backup-{{ date }}"
    cli:
      host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
      username: <username>
      password: <password>

  tasks:
    - sros_command:
        commands: <command backup>
        provider: "{{ cli }}"
      register: config

    - <task to send alarm notification>
      when: config.unreachable

    - copy:
        content: "{{ config.stdout[0] }}"
        dest: "{{ backup_dir }}/backup_conf-{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt"
      when: config.unreachable is not defined
      register: copy_result

    - <task to send alarm notification>
      when: copy_result.failed
```

Note that you will need to have Ansible version 2.7 or greater to use `ignore_unreachable`